# htaccess and mod_rewrite codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and below is my htaccess file.  However, i want a single directory to be accessable outside of the codeigniter app via my domain.com/directory.  the other directory is a forum not related to codeigniter.  how would i set up a rule in htaccess?  i dont have access to http.conf

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should already work.  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` tells mod_rewrite to ignore actual directories, and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` tells it to ignore actual files.

Comment: I am trying something, but the problem i think is that when i navigate to domain.com/directory codeigniter treats directory like a controller but i want that directory to be treated like a normal folder.  it has its own index.php and htaccess file.  Let me see how this test goes.  But do you get what i am saying?  should i still be okay?

Comment: What I am saying is I don't know why this is a problem.  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means do not rewrite if the filename is actually a folder.  One thing to try is add a trailing slash to the end of the URL: `domain.com/directory/` instead of `domain.com/directory`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to exclude any folder from being parsed to codeigniter framework as a controller.
So www.domain.com/images/ would run as normal folder, etc. There you can put your individual directives of htaccess. Best of luck!

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(folders_to_exclude_from_CI|images|css|assets|resources|robots\.txt)
```